# Compare between a char in a string to a given char

Tags: c++, c, string, strcmp

I have the following:

```
int findPar(char* str)
{
int counter=0;

while (*str) 
{
    if(str[0] == "(") <---- Warning
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if (str[0]== ")") <---- Warning
    {
        counter--;
    }
    if (counter<0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    str++;
}

if (counter!=0) 
{
    return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

The warning i get is comparison between an int and a char.

I tried to do the comparison (first char in the string vs. given char) also with strcmp like this:

```
    if (strcmp(str, ")")==0) { stuff }
```

but it never goes in to 'stuff' even when the comparison (should) be correct.

how should i do it?

Comment: Use single quotes. `")" == )\0` literally, whereas `')' == )`.

Comment: `strcmp( str, ')' ) ==0)` does not work because your are comparing the whole string char* against a single literal character. It would work if you did `strcmp( str[0], ')') == 0` I think

Comment: @EdChum `strcmp` expects it parameters to be string. ')', a char of value `41` will be converted to `(char*)41`. So the function will look into the memory address `41`, hoping to see a string and instead - BAM! Segfault.

Comment: @Imp OK, I wasn't sure which was why I annotated my guess with think, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If `str` is a C string (null-terminated array of chars), then `str[0]` is a char.

Note that the type of quotes matters! `')'` is a char, while `")"` is a string (i.e. a `')'` char followed by a null terminator).

So, you may compare two chars:

```
str[0] == ')'
```

or you may compare two strings

```
strcmp(str, ")") == 0
```

naturally, (the second works if `str` string really only contains that parenthesis).

Answer (score 7):

You're comparing a character (`str[0]`) with a `const char[N]` (`"whatever"`). You need to use single quotes because double quotes denote character arrays, whereas single quotes denote single characters:

```
if (str[0] == ')') // or *str == ')'
```

Etc.

The reason why `strcmp` was failing as well was because, while the string at some time does point to the `)`, it has more characters beyond that (i.e. is not followed immediately by a `'\0'`) so the string is not equivalent to the string `")"` which has one character.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes, `"` are string delimiters, so `")"` is a pointer to a string literal in `if(str[0] == "(")`.
You want to compare to a character, so you have to use single quotes

```
if(str[0] == '(')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `if (str[0] == ')')` etc. Note the single quotation marks (apostrophes) to denote character literals.